# Configure your SharePoint farm wizard

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-farm

After patching SharePoint 2019, we ran SP Config Wizard and after completion a page opens up instead of CA page. The display message says...Welcome! How do you want to configure your SharePoint farm with two options  1. YES, Walk me through the configuration of my farm using this wizard [ START THE WIZARD] and 2. No, I will configure everything myself [CANCEL].

Which option is correct for me to proceed, clicking on [CANCEL] it opens up CA but the upgrade status has FAILED.. and I'm not too sure about the 1st option because I already have the farm configured initially when we deploy SP, proceeding with this option might affect what we already have in place - customize branding with site collections created.

Does anyone know why, I get this prompt again and if it's necessary which option should I proceed with?

Answer (score 0):

It is a standard prompt after installing CU and you should usually choose *Cancel* or just close it.
It does not affect your *Upgrade status*.

Comment: Hi, thank you for this information. It was a little confusing to have this option pop up right the wizard was complete.